# Se me borran los valores asignados en un datatable, usando ajax

Tags: jquery, html5, ajax, datatables

Tengo el siguiente codigo html

```
 <table id="idtabledetalleventa" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th >Codigo               </th>
            <th >Cantidad             </th>
            <th >Unidad               </th>
            <th >Detalle              </th>
            <th >Precio               </th>
            <th >Desc1                </th>
            <th >Valor                </th>
            <th >Eliminar             </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="8" class="footer_detalleventa">
                <input id="idbtn_agregar" type="button" class="add habilita_escritura_btn" value="Agregar item" />
                <input id="idbtn_grabarventa" type="button" class="save grabaventa" value="Grabar Venta" />
            </th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="filas" id="fila_1" data-fila="1">
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="idcodigo_btn1" class="codigo_btn" value="Buscar" data-fila="1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idcantidad_1" type="number" class="detalle cantidad"  data-fila="1"   />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idunidad_1" type="text" class="detalle"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="iddetalle_1" type="text" class="detalle" value="" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idprecio_1" type="text" class="detalle" style="text-align:right"  readonly  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="iddesc1_1" type="number" class="detalle"   />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idvalor_1" type="text" class="detalle"   readonly />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="elimina_fila detalle_btn" value="DEL" data-idfila="fila_1"  />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="fila_2" class="filas" data-fila="2">
            <td>
                <input type="submit" id="idcodigo_btn2" class="codigo_btn"  value="Buscar" data-fila="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idcantidad_2" type="number" class="detalle cantidad"  data-fila="2"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idunidad_2" type="text" class="detalle"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="iddetalle_2" type="text" class="detalle" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idprecio_2" type="text" class="detalle" style="text-align:right"  readonly />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="iddesc1_2" type="number" class="detalle"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="idvalor_2" type="text" class="detalle"  readonly  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="elimina_fila detalle_btn" value="DEL" data-idfila="fila_2" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Me baso en el ejemplo de esta pagina:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

Dentro del document ready tengo lo siguiente:

```
 var tabla = $("#idtabledetalleventa").DataTable({
            "scrollX": true, "scrollY": "250px", "scrollCollapse": true, "searching": false, "paging": false, "ordering": false, "info": false, "autowidth": false,
        "columns":
        [
        { "width": "5%","targets":0},
        { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "5%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "50%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "5%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 },
        { "width": "5%", "targets": 0 }
        ]
        });
        //var tabla = $("#idtabledetalleventa").DataTable({ destroy: true });
        $(".footer_detalleventa").css("display", "");
        var counter = 3;

        $('.add').on('click', function () {
           var data= tabla.row.add([
                '<input id="idcodigo_btn' + counter + '" type="submit" class="codigo_btn"  value="Buscar" data-fila="' + counter + '"   />',
                '<input id="idcantidad_' + counter + '" type="number"  class="detalle cantidad" data-fila="' + counter + '" />',
                '<input id="idunidad_' + counter + '" type="text"   />',
                '<input id="iddetalle_' + counter + '" type="text"   />',
                '<input id="idprecio_' + counter + '" type="text" style="text-align:right" readonly   />',
                '<input id="iddesc1_' + counter + '" type="number"  />',
                '<input id="idvalor_' + counter + '" class="detalle" type="text"  readonly  />',
                '<input type="button" class="elimina_fila" value="DEL" data-idfila="fila_' + counter + '"  />',


            ]).draw(false);
            tabla.$('tr').addClass('filas');
            tabla.rows(data).nodes().to$().attr("id", "fila_" + counter);
            tabla.rows(data).nodes().to$().attr("data-fila", counter);

            counter++;
        });
```

Mediante un boton, copio los valores a una determinada fila de la tabla, a traves de esta forma:

```
         $("#idproductosencontrados tbody tr td input.selector").on("click", function (e) {
        // $('.selector').click(function (e) {
  //      $('.selector').on("click", function (e) {
             e.preventDefault();

                var codigosel = $(this).data("codigo");
                $("#codigo_oculto").val(codigosel);
            $("#modal_productos").modal("hide");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Notas/Leer/',
                traditional: true,
                data: { codigo: codigosel},
                DataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    var codigo = data.codigojson;
                    var nombre = data.nombrejson;
                    var unidad = data.unidadjson;
                    var precio = data.preciojson;
                    var fila = $("#idfila").val();
                    $("#idcodigo_btn" + fila.toString()).val(codigosel);
                    $("#idtabledetalleventa #idcantidad_" + fila.toString()).val("1.00");
                    //$("#idtabledetalleventa input[id=iddetalle_" + fila.toString() + "]").val(nombre);
                    $("#idtabledetalleventa input[id=iddetalle_" + fila.toString() + "]").attr("value", nombre);
                    $("#idtabledetalleventa #idunidad_" + fila.toString()).val(unidad);
                    $("#idtabledetalleventa #idprecio_" + fila.toString()).val(precio);
                    $("#idtabledetalleventa #idvalor_" + fila.toString()).val(codigosel);
                    multiplicar(1, precio, fila.toString());

                }, error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
```

Hasta ahí todo bien, los valores se asignan tal como se procede dentro del succes de ajax con json.

Pero cuando pincho la fila para que se me expanda el detalle de la tabla, los valores se pierden, existe alguna forma de solucionar este problema. Y me gustaria saber como cerrar todas las expansiones abiertas del detalle a traves de algun boton.

Answer (score 0):

Saludos Danilo,

Supongo que cuentas con un evento el cual te ayuda al momento que quieres expandir el detalle de tu tabla, este evento creo que también deberías generarlo al momento de hacer tu petición con Ajax.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, Migue y bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Te recomiendo [edit] tu pregunta y puedes seguir estos **[pasos para elaborar una buena respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**. Saludos.

Comment: Hola @Migue en el ejemplo de esta pagina https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html
el cual me estaba basando, hace la expansión debido a las librerías que permite hacerlo.
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.1.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min.js

Cuando envio los datos a una fila mediante Json, se pasan bien, pero cuando se hace la expansión, se pierde los datos. El evento es efectuado por las librerías que te comente. Por eso en el link de la pagina sale con detalle como es.